# Create a column in a pandas DataFrame using the previously computed value

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I have for example the following input DataFrame:

```
> df = pandas.DataFrame({'x': [1, 6, 8, 5, 2, 6, 12]})
> df
    x
0   1
1   6
2   8
3   5
4   2
5   6
6  12
```

And I would like to create the column y such that:

`y[i] = 0` if `x < 4`,

`y[i] = 1` if `x > 6`

and `y[i] = y[i - 1]` if `4 <= x <= 6`

So that with the example above the output would be:

```
    x  y
0   1  0
1   6  0
2   8  1
3   5  1
4   2  0
5   6  0
6  12  1
```

What is the best way to do this? A simple `apply()` does not seem to work as I did not find a way to reference a previously computed value in the column that is being created by the `apply()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html#numpy.select) followed by [`.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html#pandas.Series.fillna):

```
>>> df['y'] = np.select([df['x'] < 4, 6 < df['x']], [0, 1], np.nan)
>>> df['y'] = df['y'].fillna(method='ffill').astype('int')
>>> df
    x  y
0   1  0
1   6  0
2   8  1
3   5  1
4   2  0
5   6  0
6  12  1
```